# Contar número de ficheiros c#

Tags: c#

Boa tarde! 
Tenho um listView com várias checkbox's. Quero fazer a contagem de todos os ficheiros das checkbox que estão seleccionadas. 
Fiz o seguinte código, mas não está dando certo.

```
if (listView.Items[j].CheckState == CheckState.Checked)
                {
                    string countVersions = listView.CheckedItems.Count.ToString();


                        {

                        try
                        {


                            UltraListViewItem item = listView.Items[j];
                            {
                                int countVerao = int.Parse(countVersions);
                                for (int i = 0; i <= countVerao + 1; i++)

                                {
                                    DataBaseUpdate dataBaseUpdate = mUpdater.GetDataBaseUpdateByID((int)item.Tag);

                                    DataBaseUpdateFilesCollection dataBaseUpdateFilesCollection = mUpdater.GetDatabaseUpdateFilesByDataBaseUpdate(dataBaseUpdate.ID);

                                    countFiles = dataBaseUpdateFilesCollection.Count.ToString();

                                    totalFiles = totalFiles + int.Parse(countFiles);
                                }
                                DataBaseUpdateFilesCollection dataBaseUpdateFilesCollection1 = mUpdater.GetDatabaseUpdateFilesByDataBaseUpdate(dataBaseUpdate.ID);
                                mProgressBarPercPerElem = (perc /= (int.Parse(countFiles)));

                                foreach (DataBaseUpdateFiles filesSql in dataBaseUpdateFilesCollection1)
                                {


                                }
```

O meu problema está aqui. Ele está sempre a passar no primeiro elemento do listview, e eu quero que ele percorra todos os que estiverem selecionados. 
for (int i = 0; i <= countVerao + 1; i++)

Alguém me pode ajudar ?

Comment: não entendi muito bem o que precisa, tente explicar melhor por favor. Qual o tipo de retorno da variável dataBaseUpdateFilesCollection.Count e  listView.CheckedItems.Count ? porque você às joga para String e depois tens de fazer int.Parse() ?

Comment: A dataBaseUpdateFilesCollection.Count diz-me quantos ficheiros estão associados a essa Versão. Na primeira versão são 77, na segunda 60 por exemplo.

Comment: pode colocar o código completo, onde a variável j é declarado por exemplo ?

Comment: Tive que fazer de outra forma. Obrigada na mesma.